# android ContentObserver call when settings changed

Tags: android

I am using ContentObserver to check if my mobile settings are changed.

```
public class SettingsContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
    Context mContext;
    public SettingsContentObserver(Handler handler, Context context) {
        super(handler);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        // code here
    }
}
```

It's working fine. How can I check which setting is changed - like brightness or volume or ringtone?

Here I register this contentobserver:

```
SettingsContentObserver mSettingsContentObserver = new SettingsContentObserver( new Handler(),serviceContext );
        serviceContext.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
                android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true,
                mSettingsContentObserver);
```

Comment: you can use `android.database.CursorJoiner` for that purpose

Comment: how can i use it will tou help me with some code @pskink

Comment: google for CursorJoiner, skip stackoverflow questions and official google sites

Comment: then will you please share me a link?

Comment: but for that particulat `Uri` you can just override `onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri)` method and use `uri` parameter (note that it does not work with every "observable" `Uri`)

Comment: @psking will tou please tell me with some code

Comment: like i said: override that method, the same way you overrode onChange with boolean parameter

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in comments, you can do this:

```
@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange, @Nullable Uri uri) {
    super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
    Log.v("SettingsContentObserver", "Uri is: " + uri.toString() + "\t");
}
```

uri.toString() will give you which setting changed